# How to create image from hindi unicode text in php

Tags: php, unicode

I am trying to create image from hindi unicode text. The code works fine but the problem is that i typed अमित to write in image but after creating image the word अमित change into अमति.

Any solution???
Here is my code:-

```
$text=$_POST["text"];
htextToImg($text);

function htextToImg($text, $image_width=500, $colour = array(0,0,0), $background =   array(255,255,255)) {
$font = "ARIALUNI.TTF";
$line_height = 15;
$padding = 15;
$text = wordwrap($text, ($image_width/10));
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($image_width,((count($lines) * $line_height))+5);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, $background[0], $background[1], $background[2]);
imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,imagesx($im),imagesy($im),$white);
// write the text to image 
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$size = 13;
$angle = 0;
$x = 5;
$y = 14;  
for($l=0;$l<count($lines);$l++)
{
imagettftext($im, $size, $angle, 2, $y, $color, $font, $lines[$l]);
$y =$y+15;   
}
imagejpeg($im, 'dir/img.jpg');
}
```

Comment: `but after creating image the word अमित change into अमति`. I'm probably a word racist, but they both look the same to me

Comment: look carefully in the correct word the ि is on म but in image it is on त ....both are different in meaning and pronunciation

Comment: let me tell you one thing more if i print the variable $text <?php echo $text;?> it prints  अमित but after passing it into the function it change into अमति

Comment: Do you by any chance print it after `wordwrap()` inside the function ?

Comment: yes it prints correctly on the browser but in image it changes...please try the code yourself

Comment: Properly formatting this text with all OpenType features working correctly is probably outside what `imagettftext` can do -- it's a tough job even for professional text layout software. See, for example, the last comment in [this Typophile thread](http://typophile.com/node/73297). In your case, your browser supports the necessary features and so can show it correctly, but php cannot.